# How can I set an unknown number of IDs?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the following code which loops through an array of an unknown length. I want to change the style of one of the paragraphs by JavaScript HTML DOM, and want to change it on **one** single paragraph. Right now the class name is demo2 but I want to set it to something like demo_x.

```
-for (x in c){
  tr
    td.icon
      .div
        img(src=c[x].companyLogo, width= '45px',style=' max-height=45px;')
      .div(style='padding-left:10px;')
        a(style='font-weight: 550; display:block;')=c[x].companyName
        a(style='display:block;')=c[x].companyDomain
    td
      span.demo1
      span.demo2
      span.less(style= 'color: #1d8bea;',onclick="toggleFunction()")
    //This script evaluates the array length, divides it into two arrays, and also does the show more/less effect.
    include ../public/javascripts/slice.pug
    td
      p(style='display: inline; color: #6e6e6e;') #{c[x].location.CountryCode}
      span ,&nbsp;
      a(style='display: inline;') #{c[x].location.State}
      span ,&nbsp;
      a(style='display: inline;') #{c[x].location.City}
    td
      p(style='color: #6e6e6e;') #{e[x]}
    td
      a  #{d[x]}
-}
script.
    function toggleFunction() {
        var t = document.getElementsByClassName("demo2");
        if (t.style.display === "none") {
            t.style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            t.style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which are the conditions to perform the CSS class change to the specific HTML element?

Comment: See line 12 above: span.less(style= 'color: #1d8bea;',onclick="toggleFunction()").
So when I click this span element.

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong :) try my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the for loop to set class each, like this:

```
- var c =  ['a', 'b', 'c'];


- for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    div(class='row-'+c[i])
- }
```

Output:

```
<div class="row-a"></div>
<div class="row-b"></div>
<div class="row-c"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've understood your question.

You should use the "this" keyword: when the function is called by the onclick, you'll bring the whole DOM element where the "onclick" has been performed as "this".

In a nutshell:

```
function toggleFunction() {

        if (this.style.display === "none") {
            this.style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            this.style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
```